# Azure Web App - 504 Gateway error while connecting Azure SQL DB over https

Tags: timeout, azure-sql-database, gateway, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

I am using the following environment for my web app:

Web App Hosted on Azure, using Azure Verizon Standard CDN with HTTPS enabled. DNS on Azure pointing to endpoint. SQL Database on Azure (basically, the entire app, DB and environment are on Azure).

I am getting `504 Gateway Timeout` error for this link:

`https://www.kunshtech.com/myMagicStringBlogAccount/Login`

My guess is that it's an issue with the HTTPS request.

I connected the same link on localhost using visual studio and using the Azure database and that is working fine. I also used HTTPS on localhost which is also working fine.

I am using this connection string:

`connectionString="Server=tcp:mydbname.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={mycatalogname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={username};Password={mypassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=300;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I also have set the firewall rules for Azure SQL DB to accept the IP from the app server.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a retry logic is recommended for error 504 based on [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific).

Please enable [diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to debug your application:

Hope this helps.